# Somebody born or somebody are born?

Tags: grammar

Is it appropriate to say 'Young children born and grow up in their community'? Or it needs to be changed to ' Young children are born and grow up in their community'?

Comment: Your two verbs in in the first example sentence are in two tenses, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @kaipmdh "Born" isn't even a tense. The present is "bear", the simple past is "bore", and the present passive is "are born", but there's no tense that's just "born".

Answer (score 1):

The latter is correct as you need a coordination of tensed verbs. *Born* is a participle and may not head a main clause, only a subordinate one.

*Young children born in their community* would be a noun phrase with a past participial modifier equal to:

> Young children who are born in their community

which cannot stand alone as a main clause.